# URL safe base 64 encoding in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, url-encoding

I have a requirement where I need to encode a string to URL Safe Base 64 encoding in oracle database.

I have tried the below

```
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('example1@domain.com')))
```

Could someone please provide references of doing it URL safe. Also we have been getting feedback that characters in hex format instead of base64.

Any references to understanding to do it in oracle would be appreciated. All references I have been getting are of Object oriented languages like Java, C# and python.

Comment: Do you mean `UTL_URL.ESCAPE('example1@domain.com')` or `HTF.ESCAPE_URL(`example1@domain.com`)`?

Comment: I have to encode an email address. Seems like either of them are not encoding.